# train() error with method = "QDA" and value = "finalModel"

Tags: r, r-caret, quadratic

I ran the `train()` with `method = "lda" value = "finalModel"` without errors to completion, changed to `method = "qda"` and I get errors... I am working on Generative Models.

```
library(dslabs) 
library(caret)
data("tissue_gene_expression")
set.seed(1993) 
y <- tissue_gene_expression$y
x <- tissue_gene_expression$x
x <- x[, sample(ncol(x), 10)]

fit_qda <- train(x, y, method = "qda", value = "finalModel")
fit_qda$results
```

I should get TWO genes to drive the algorithm...

I am getting:

> Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
>     Error: Stopping

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the data that you are using? I have never use the argument `value` in `train` and I have not found any reference in the documentation. What would that argument be  suppose to do?

Comment: @c1au61o_HH The data is from `dslabs`.

Comment: Got it, not sure why I overlooked that info.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error or train the mode. In my case I get  that "some group is too small for 'qda' " (determined by the fact that the group `placenta` counts only 6 elements`

Answer (score 0):

Neither `train()` nor `MASS::qda()` have a `value` argument.

If you look, your code gives warnings:

```
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

The warnings are:

```
some group is too small for 'qda'
```

QDA needs to be able to compute a full (non-singular) covariance matrix within each class and you don't have enough data (relative to your predictors) to do that in this examples